# Swift: How to properly serve a Realm in deployment

Tags: ios, database, swift, deployment, realm

I have an iOS application written in Swift using Realm as a database working locally on my computer.

Right now, when I make reads and writes from Realm, I believe it is to and from a local file on my computer. Obviously this will not work in deployment, because the Realm file needs to be the same for every user, and every user will have the ability to change the Realm, so it seems that the Realm must be on a server.

How can I make it so that when users perform reads and writes to Realm, it maps to the Realm file on a server. What type of server should I use? I currently have an Amazon S3 account, should I just store the Realm file in a bucket and download and rewrite the Realm file anytime someone makes a change (though that seems highly inefficient)?

**EDIT:**

To ask this in a simpler way, what is the standard way to store user data in iOS applications on a server?

Comment: sounds race-conditiony to have a bunch of users downloading and rewriting a file when they make changes

Comment: So how does Facebook implement that? They allow users to create posts on their phone that are then updated to other people's phones and what not. So does Twitter, LinkedIn, and a million other apps. It seems like basic functionality to me.

Comment: I imagine they add rows to their table and push them out to other peoples phones, or other peoples phones pull the data every so often. There is probably also some mechanism that orchestrates so many users adding things to the same tables at the same time.

Comment: @WillM. Yes there is, and those are called [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415350/5389870). Unfortunately what you're proposing doesn't seem to be possible, at least yet.

For what you're proposing you're better off using a more traditional server-side database.

**EDIT:**

> To ask this in a simpler way, what is the standard way to store user data in iOS applications on a server?

That's quite a broad question, but normally saving data on a server is done through using your own custom API + back-end, or utilising a back-end SaaS (such as the soon-to-be-defunct Parse, or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/).

If you want to store user data on a server you need to do this through network requests on the front-end, and your API would modify the database accordingly. You would *never* modify the database directly on your front-end.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what I should use specifically? Is Core Data or SQLite a solid option for what I want?

Comment: [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) could be a solid option if you're not expecting too much traffic.

Comment: @rigdonmr Realm is a mobile database, so basically a replacement for Core Data, it's not really meant to be used as a server-side database, but to store data locally on the device. I also updated my answer to reflect your edit.